# Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Code:

```js
function fun3(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ISWCprDWDl04k472ceVHVjjpMK7bysme5f2rApwJpJA');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('18D8T71n5GOR33imbqdTPeJ-0oBCm6e30cVAKjueFc8Y');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(rowData);
  body.insertParagraph(0,ss.getName())
  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var table = body.appendTable(rowData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

The exception I am getting:

Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable. at fun3(Code:37:20)

Comment: How do you get the table data, the `rowData` var? Can you share a copy of the doc and the sheet to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that in your situation, the date object might be included in `rowData`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var rowData = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var rowData = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
```

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)